# How can I display yesterday with options format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is React.js project. I need to display today and yesterday as :

```
6 June
5 June
```

file.js:

```
const date = new Date();
const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
let today = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)
let yesterday = new Date(date)
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1)
//yesterday = yesterday.toDateString()
yesterday = yesterday.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)

export { today, yesterday };
```

HTML:

```
<p> Today : { today } </p>
```

Today is displayed as:

```
6 June
```

But yesterday get error:

```
<p> Yesterday: { yesterday ) </p>
Uncaught TypeError: yesterday.toLocaleDateString is not a function
```

How can I display yesterday with options format?

Comment: remove `yesterday = yesterday.toDateString()` ? since then u will be calling toLocaleDateString on a string

Answer (score 0):

file.js:

```
const date = new Date();
const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
let today = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)
let yesterday = new Date(date)
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1)
yesterday = yesterday.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)

export { today, yesterday };
```